# NSMutableDictionary<NSString*,NSMutableArray*>

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am sorry, I am not good at English, maybe cann`t describ the problem clearly. Then the code is:

I declared a property as my datasource

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableDictionary<NSString*,NSMutableArray*> *sectionData;
```

and initialized like  `self.sectionData[fir] = [NSMutableArray array];` make sure there is an NSMutableArray object in the dictionary. but when i fetch the data like

```
NSMutableArray *subArray =self.sectionData[self.sectionNames[indexPath.section]];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([subArray class]));
```

the console shows: __NSArrayI
why is that happens, why is not NSMutableArray, and now I cannot delete the some Items in the datasource,

The code that i add initialize my dataSource is :

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sectionNames
{
    if (!_sectionNames) {
        _sectionNames = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.sectionData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSString *sourceStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"states" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        NSArray *states = [sourceStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        [states enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString  * str, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            if ([str isNotNullOrWhiteSpace]) {
                unichar chars[] = {[str characterAtIndex:0]};
                NSString *fir = [[NSString stringWithCharacters:chars length:1] uppercaseString];

                if (![_sectionNames containsObject:fir] && ![fir isEqualToString:@""]) {

                    [_sectionNames addObject:[fir uppercaseString]];
                    self.sectionData[fir] = [NSMutableArray array];
                }
                [self.sectionData[fir] addObject:str];
            }
        }];

        //对sectionData中的array元素对象进行排序
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.sectionData enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSMutableArray *obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            weakSelf.sectionData[key] = [[obj sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

                return [[obj1 uppercaseString] compare:[obj2 uppercaseString]];
            }] copy];
        }];

    }
    return _sectionNames;
}
```

and then I delete some selected items:

```
- (void)doDelete:(UIBarButtonItem*)deleteBtn
{
    NSArray *deletedIndexpathes = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    if (deletedIndexpathes.count == 0) return;
    //sort
    deletedIndexpathes = [deletedIndexpathes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    deletedIndexpathes = [[deletedIndexpathes reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects];

    //delete data
    NSMutableIndexSet *emptySections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet]; // keep track of what sections get emptied

    [deletedIndexpathes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath  * indexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        NSMutableArray *subArray =(NSMutableArray *)self.sectionData[self.sectionNames[indexPath.section]];

        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([subArray class]));
//        [ subArray removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.item];

//        NSLog(@"%@",self.sectionData[self.sectionNames[indexPath.section]]);
        //如果一个section里面没有item，追踪下来
//        if (cArray.count == 0) {
////            [emptySections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section]];
//            [emptySections addIndex:indexPath.section];
//        }
    }];
```

but the subArray is an NSArray that I cann`t delete....

Comment: `[aa class]`, you mean `[subArray class]`? You may do `self.sectionData[fir] = [NSMutableArray array];` but where do you set the data exactly?

Comment: ooh, it`s [subArray class]. the data have been set in the getter method..

Comment: How do you add data? For example, if do `self.sectionData[fir] = [NSMutableArray array];` but then do `self.sectionData[fir] = @[dataFetch1, dataFetch2];` you're giving a `NSArray` there.

Comment: I add data  using   [self.sectionData[fir] addObject:str].. is it a NSArray?

Comment: LLDB is useful!!! Please learn how to debug with it.

Comment: @Justlike  I already use LLDB  and it shows  "subArray" is An NSArray instance ...not an NSMutableArray..

Comment: @Evoque Its better to post the code of `*.m`.

Comment: @Justlike  I have post the related code.. please help me.....Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 weakSelf.sectionData[key] = [[obj sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

                return [[obj1 uppercaseString] compare:[obj2 uppercaseString]];
            }] copy];
```

to

```
 weakSelf.sectionData[key] = [[obj sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

            return [[obj1 uppercaseString] compare:[obj2 uppercaseString]];
        }] mutableCopy];
```

> `copy` -->  `mutableCopy`.